# Drawer reopen Sometime when change screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer

I am using react navigation drawer v6 with custom header when click on hamburger menu it show drawer its work fine but when I navigate from drawer it change screen and reopen drawer sometime . I dont its a bug Or something else .I am attaching gif of behavior. How can i fixed this Issue.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by adding **useLegacyImplementation** to **true** in my drawer navigator. it worked for me . [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/10503) is reference